# Multiline cells do not vertically center in tabularray table

Tags: tabularray

I am attempting to vertically centre a multiline cell, so far without success.  In the following diagram A is fine, but B/C seem to be pushed to the top, rather than placed around the middle of the box.  Also the spacing between them is larger than I would prefer:

[image]

The main table definition is:

```
    \begin{longtblr}[theme = fancy, entry=none,label=none]{
            colspec = {|l|l|Q[h,l]|},
            stretch = 0,
            columns = {colsep=1mm},
            column{1} = {leftsep=0pt},
            column{3} = {rightsep=0pt},
        }
```

and the multicell:

```
        \inst{B} &
        \R{1},\DSXB{2} &
        \SetCell[r=2]{m} \Wrap{\RSFullFull{\add}} \\*
        
        \inst{C} &
        \R{1},\DLXB{2} & 
        -- \\ \hline
```

(Horizontal and vertical lines added just to see the issue more clearly: will be removed)

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}  
\usepackage[papersize={105mm,297mm}, margin=5mm]{geometry}   
\pagenumbering{gobble} 

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes.misc, shapes,arrows,chains, arrows.meta, calc, decorations.pathmorphing}


\usepackage{tabularray}

%%%%% tabularray settings

\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
}

\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-tag}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-sep}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{caption-text}{default}{}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{default}{}
 

\tikzset{ 
    Register/.style={
        rectangle,
        minimum height = 1cm,
        minimum width = 8cm,    
    }, 
    point/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=red},
    sizenode/.style = {font=\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily, white},
    node distance = 5mm and 10mm, 
    >=Kite, 
    every node/.style={transform shape}, 
}
     

\newcommand\RSFullFull[2][]{
    \node (x) [Register] {};
    
    \fill [black!20] (x.south west) +(0,0) rectangle +(20,5); 
}
 

\def\add{\raisebox{-1.5em}{{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont{+}}}}  
\newcommand\lowersub[1]{\raisebox{-0.1ex}{\textsubscript{#1}}}
\newcommand\raisesup[1]{\raisebox{0.1ex}{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\newcommand\subsup[2]{\rlap{\lowersub{#1}}\raisesup{#2}}   
\newcommand{\R}[1]{R\textsubscript{#1}}  
\newcommand{\RE}[1]{R\subsup{#1}{E}} 
\newcommand{\I}[1]{I\textsubscript{#1}} 
\newcommand{\D}[1]{D\textsubscript{#1}} 
\newcommand{\DS}[1]{D\subsup{#1}{12}}
\newcommand{\DL}[1]{D\subsup{#1}{20}}
\newcommand{\X}[1]{X\textsubscript{#1}} 
\newcommand{\B}[1]{B\textsubscript{#1}} 
\newcommand{\inst}[1]{\textbf{#1}} 
\newcommand{\DSB}[1]{\DS{#1}(\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DLB}[1]{\DL{#1}(\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DSXB}[1]{\DS{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DLXB}[1]{\DL{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DXB}[1]{\D{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}

\newcommand\Wrap[1]{ 
    \scalebox{0.3}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[ scale=1.0, baseline=(current bounding box.center)]  % .north
            #1
            \useasboundingbox 
                ([shift={(0mm,2mm)}]current bounding box.north east) 
                rectangle 
                ([shift={(0mm,-2mm)}]current bounding box.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}
 
\begin{document}
        \begin{longtblr}[theme = fancy, entry=none,label=none]{
                colspec = {|l|l|Q[h,l]|},
                stretch = 0,
                columns = {colsep=1mm},
                column{1} = {leftsep=0pt},
                column{3} = {rightsep=0pt},
            }
        
            \hline
        
            \inst{A} & 
            R\textsubscript{1},R\textsubscript{2} &
            \Wrap{\RSFullFull{\add}} \\ \hline 
            
            \inst{B} &
            \R{1},\DSXB{2} &
            \SetCell[r=2]{m} \Wrap{\RSFullFull{\add}} \\*
            
            \inst{C} &
            \R{1},\DLXB{2} & 
            -- \\ \hline
 
 
        \end{longtblr} 
 
 
\end{document}
```

For @Zarko:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See if the following MWE gives what you after:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[papersize={105mm,297mm}, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                calc,chains, 
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning, 
                shapes, shapes.misc}
\usepackage{tabularray}

%%%%% tabularray settings
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{
}

\tikzset{
    Register/.style={
        rectangle,
        minimum height = 1cm,
        minimum width = 8cm,
    },
    point/.style={circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=2pt, fill=red},
    sizenode/.style = {font=\fontsize{22}{22}\selectfont\bfseries\sffamily, white},
    node distance = 5mm and 10mm,
    >=Kite,
    every node/.style={transform shape},
}

\newcommand\RSFullFull[2][]{
    \node (x) [Register] {};

    \fill [black!20] (x.south west) +(0,0) rectangle +(20,5);
}


\def\add{\raisebox{-1.5\baselineskip}{{\fontsize{20}{20}\selectfont{+}}}}
\newcommand\lowersub[1]{\raisebox{-0.1ex}{\textsubscript{#1}}}
\newcommand\raisesup[1]{\raisebox{0.1ex}{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\newcommand\subsup[2]{\rlap{\lowersub{#1}}\raisesup{#2}}
\newcommand{\R}[1]{R\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\RE}[1]{R\subsup{#1}{E}}
\newcommand{\I}[1]{I\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\D}[1]{D\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\DS}[1]{D\subsup{#1}{12}}
\newcommand{\DL}[1]{D\subsup{#1}{20}}
\newcommand{\X}[1]{X\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\B}[1]{B\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\inst}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\DSB}[1]{\DS{#1}(\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DLB}[1]{\DL{#1}(\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DSXB}[1]{\DS{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DLXB}[1]{\DL{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DXB}[1]{\D{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}

\newcommand\Wrap[1]{
    \scalebox{0.3}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-1.5ex] current bounding box.center)}]  % .north
            #1
            \useasboundingbox
                (current bounding box.north east)
                rectangle
                (current bounding box.south west);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
theme = fancy, 
entry=none,
label=none]{vlines,
            colspec = {Q[font=\bfseries] % <---
                       l c},
            colsep=1mm,                  % <---
            vspan = even                 % <---
            }
    \hline
A   &   \R{1},\R{2} 
        &   \Wrap{\RSFullFull{\add}}    \\
    \hline
B   &   \R{1},\DSXB{2} 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{m} \Wrap{\RSFullFull{\add}} \\*
C   &   \R{1},\DLXB{2}
        &                               \\
    \hline
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
Purpose of gray box in the last column is not clear. Its definition is (to my opinion) to complicated. You may consider the following solution:

```
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[papersize={105mm,297mm}, margin=5mm]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgadventor}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                calc,chains, 
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                positioning, 
                shapes, shapes.misc}
\newcommand\GrayBox[1]{\tikz[baseline] 
                        \node[minimum width=\linewidth, minimum height=8ex, fill=gray!30] {#1};
                    }
\usepackage{tabularray}
%%%%% tabularray settings
\NewTblrTheme{fancy}{}

\newcommand\lowersub[1]{\raisebox{-0.1ex}{\textsubscript{#1}}}
\newcommand\raisesup[1]{\raisebox{0.1ex}{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\newcommand\subsup[2]{\rlap{\lowersub{#1}}\raisesup{#2}}
\newcommand{\R}[1]{R\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\RE}[1]{R\subsup{#1}{E}}
\newcommand{\I}[1]{I\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\D}[1]{D\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\DS}[1]{D\subsup{#1}{12}}
\newcommand{\DL}[1]{D\subsup{#1}{20}}
\newcommand{\X}[1]{X\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\B}[1]{B\textsubscript{#1}}
\newcommand{\inst}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\DSB}[1]{\DS{#1}(\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DLB}[1]{\DL{#1}(\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DSXB}[1]{\DS{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DLXB}[1]{\DL{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}
\newcommand{\DXB}[1]{\D{#1}(\X{#1},\B{#1})}


\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[
%theme = fancy, 
entry=none,
label=none]{colspec = {@{} Q[m, font=\bfseries] % <---
                       l 
                       X[c] @{}},               % <---
            colsep=1mm,                     % <---
            vspan = even                    % <---
            }
A   &   \R{1},\R{2} 
        &   \GrayBox                   \\
B   &   \R{1},\DSXB{2} 
        & \SetCell[r=2]{c}     \GrayBox{}   \\*
C   &   \R{1},\DLXB{2}
        &                               \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks much better, many thanks.  But I don't follow the whys and wherefores of the changes, I'm afraid.  Might you be able to explain them to me?

Comment: @Ian, see addendum. It may be more clear. In both examples important changes are in `longtblr` preamble marked by `% <---`.

Comment: the graybox is simply a place holder for a tree of tikz instructions.  For the purposes of a MWE, I should have replaced it: my bad.  What does the FONT in the COLSPEC do?  Is that the solution here, or the VSPAN, or are both needed?  Is the change to the colseps relevant to the fix?

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the separation of B and C?  Or should I just use a raisebox?

Comment: @Ian, for most of your question you can find in `tabularray` package better answer that I can copy/rewrite them from there. Documentation is concise and well illustrated. From `colspec` is obvious tha `font` define font in columns (`\bfseries` in the first column), `vspan` determine rows span at multi row cells. In your case define equal height of spanned rows. Why you like to reduce colsep? result is very ugly! Of course it is possible, but I will not encourage you to do this.

Comment: Ah, that /changes/ the font.  So, I think the actual guts of the fix is the different colspec and vspan, correct?  (In answer to your question, yes its ugly with the vlines, but fine without them: this is a table in a very narrow column and I don't need the side borders and do need all the space I can for the diagram.  I'll add a picture in moment so you can see what I'm doing with it.

Comment: What's the advantage of X[] for the third column over the Q[h,l]?  Can't see that explained in the documentation.

Comment: See 1.6 Column Types, page 9, package documentation.

Comment: I saw it.  It says "Tabularray package supports all normal column types, as well as the extendable X column type, which first occurred in tabularx package and was largely improved by tabu package".  I'm still struggling to understand what the difference is.

Comment: @Ian, for `X˛` you find at my link "Tabularray package supports all normal column types, as well as the extendable X column type, which first occurred in tabularx package and was largely improved by tabu package" and "You can define new column types with \NewColumnType command. For example, in tabularray package,
b and X columns are defined as special `Q` columns:
`\NewColumnType{X}[1][]{Q[co=1,#1]}`.

Comment: and In section 1.3 Cell Alignment is stated: "From time to time, you may want to specify the horizontal and vertical alignment of cells at the same time `Tabularray` provides a `Q` column for this (In fact, `Q` column is the only primitive column, other columns are defined as `Q` columns with some options):"

Comment: Indeed.  But co is defined only as "coefficient for the extendable column (X column)" without further explanation.  I find the whole thing terribly obtuse.  What's the advantage of X (or Q co=1, if you prefer)?

Comment: @Ian, this site is not forum. If you have new problem, please ask new question. If my answer help you, it will be nice from you to upvote it or even accept it.